# All possible pairs

Tags: java, math, combinations, probability

Given a set of numbers, from 1 to n, I need to model all sets of all possible pairs.

In other words, one drawed set consists of all numbers. Numbers are paired. If the count is odd - one entry with one number is allowed (in fact it's required). Sets need to be unique, i.e. pair [1,2] is the same as [2,1] (edited: and solution: [1,2] [3,4] is the same as [3,4] [1,2]).

For instance, when n equals 5, following sets can be created:

```
[1,2] [3,4] [5]
[1,2] [3,5] [4]
[1,2] [4,5] [3]
[1,3] [2,4] [5]
[1,3] [2,5] [4]
[1,3] [4,5] [2]
....
```

I am almost able to model the solution, but the uniqueness constraint is hard for me to implement.

Moreover - I feel like my solution lacks in performance. I now that the problem space is big, but for me even for n=12 computation takes more than 5 minutes.

```
public void compute(HashSet<Number> numbers, ArrayList<Pair> pairs) {
    if (numbers.size() <= 1) {
        print(pairs);
    } else {
        for (Number number1 : numbers) {
            for (Number number2 : numbers) {
                if (number1 != number2) {
                    Set<Number> possibleNumbers = new HashSet<Number>(numbers);
                    List<Pair> allPairs = new ArrayList<Pair>(pairs);

                    possibleNumbers.remove(number1);
                    possibleNumbers.remove(number2);
                    allPairs.add(new Pair(number1, number2));

                    compute(possibleNumbers, allPairs);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

compute(numbers, new ArrayList<Pair>());
```

For n=3 I get doubled set of solutions:

```
[0 1] [2] 
[0 2] [1] 
[1 0] [2] 
[1 2] [0] 
[2 0] [1] 
[2 1] [0]
```

So: how should I implement the problem to get rid of the duplicates. How can I improve the implementation to speed up the processing?

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Comment: does the order of pairs matter? is `[1 2] [3 4]` the same as `[3 4] [1 2]`?

Comment: it doesn't matter. Both solutions are the same

Comment: by "a set of numbers from 1 to n" do you mean that there are no duplicates? i.e. 1 to 5 is always 1,2,3,4,5 and never 1,1,3,4,5?

Comment: yes, you are right. Numbers are unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things you can do:

### **1) The bad thing:**

You can continue with your current approach but when adding the pairs you need to:

a) make sure that each pair is always in some kind of order, for instance always `[smallerNumber, biggerNumber]`

b) keep the allPairs list sorted

Then when you finish computation it will be trivial to remove duplicates. This is a bad approach as it will be really slow.

### **2) You can use a different algorithm:**

I will make here 2 assumptions:

- it is a set so we have no duplicates
- they can be easily sorted i.e. for 1 to 5 we know it's going to be 1,2,3,4,5 (but it also should work for cases 1,3,5,6)

Basically we will have a recursive algorithm (like yours). The input will be "numbers" -> an ordered (ascending order) list, the output will be a set of lists of pairs. Let's again call this method compute(List numbers).

-> the base case when the input list "numbers" has 1 or 2 elements. In that case return a set containing one list containing one "pair" containing either that 1 element or both of them. I.e. numbers = [2,3] or numbers = [2] then you return a set containing one list containing one "pair" either (2,3) or (3).

-> for each pair of numbers in list "numbers"  that contains the first element (i.e. in the first level of recursion for numbers = [1,2,3,4,5] it would be [1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [1,5], [1,6]) call `Set<List<Pair> result = compute(numbers.minus(currentPair))`. Iterate over that set and add the current pair at the beginning of each element.

Example:

```
result = empty
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
first = (1,2), compute([3,4,5])
    first = (3,4), compute([5])
        return (5)
    result = result + [(3,4)(5)]
    first = (3,5) compute([4])
        return (4)
    result = result + [(3,5),(4)] (a this point result is [ [(3,4)(5)], [(3,5)(4)] ]
add (1,2) to each list in result which gives us [ [(1,2)(3,4)(5)], [(1,2)(3,5)(4)] ]

first = (1,3), compute([2,4,5])
    first = (2,4), compute([5])
        return (5)
    result = result + [(2,4)(5)]
    first = (2,5) compute([4])
        return (4)
    result = result + [(2,5),(4)] (a this point result is [ [(2,4)(5)], [(2,5)(4)] ]
add (1,3) to each list in result which gives us [ [(1,3)(2,4)(5)], [(1,3)(2,5)(4)] ]
at this point we have:
[ [(1,2)(3,4)(5)], [(1,2)(3,5)(4)], [(1,3)(2,4)(5)], [(1,3)(2,5)(4)] ]
```

Continue this for (1,4), (1,5) and (1,6) and you're done. You don't have to do it starting with (2,3) and doing compute([1,4,5]) because that would result in duplicates.

This algorithm should also hold for even sets.

Haven't tested it, don't have a proof but looks ok, should be easy to code and if it works then it should be pretty fast as it will only make only necessary computations.

In code (I have written the whole code here so it is completely not tested and might contain compilation and logical errors!):

```
public Set<List<Pair>> compute(List<Integer> numbers) {
    if(numbers.size() < 3) {
            // Base case
        List<Pair> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Pair(numbers));
        Set<List<Pair>> result = new HashSet<>();
        result.add(list);
        return result;
    } else {
        Set<List<Pair>> result = new HashSet<ArrayList<>>();
        // We take each pair that contains the 1st element
        for(int i = 1; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
            Pair first = new Pair(numbers.get(0), numbers.get(i));
            // This is the input for next level of recursion
            // Our numbers list w/o the current pair
            List<Integers> nextStep = new ArrayList<>(numbers);
            nextStep.remove(i);
            nextStep.remove(0);
            Set<List<Pair>> intermediate = null;
            if(nextStep.size() % 2 == 0) {
                intermediate = compute(nextStep);
            } else {
                intermediate = compute(numbers).addAll( firstElementSingle(numbers) ),compute( nextStep );
            }
            for(List<Pair> list : intermediate ) {
                // We add the current pair at the beginning
                list.add(0, first);
            }
            result.addAll(intermediate);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty curious myself if I missed something, so I'm looking forward to your feedback :-)

**@EDIT:**

As @yusuf pointed out this would miss some permutations when the input is an odd list. It would miss all the results where [1] is the single element.

But if I'm not mistaken in such case (odd number of elements) this should work:

```
compute(numbers).addAll( firstElementSingle(numbers) )
```

Where firstElementSingle is:

```
private Set<List<Integer>> firstElementSingle(List<Integer> numbers) {
    Set<List<Integer>> result compute(numbers.subList(1,numbers.size()) );
    for(List<Integer> list : result) {
        list.add(numbers.get(0));
    }
    return result;
}
```

And still would generate only the necessary results.

Comment: You are almost right! There is one problem when we're losing the permutations. Since the singular elements stays always at the end of the array, it won't be possible to make first half of the elements to be those singular elements. E.g. for 1,2,3,4,5 there will never be a situation, where 1 is alone ([1]). I'll try to introduce some meaningful flag

Comment: you are right! but in that case wouldn't it be enough to run it first for the whole input array, for instance (1,2,3,4,5) which would give result1 and then again for the array without the first element (2,3,4,5) and add the (1) to each list of that set which would give result2 and combine result1 and result2? It would still generate only the necessary lists. You would only need a switch if(even) compute(numbers) else join(compute(numbers),compute(numbers.withoutFirst))

Comment: So in fact - not really... I've pointed out the situation where 1 is a singular element, but for n=5 we are able to get [2] singular as well (among with one scenario when [3] is alone). I've added additional flag, which determines if singular object was already used in given path, but that makes some result  be duplicated again. As you mentioned, removing duplicates is not a good approach. What's interesting, I've found out, that adding one number to make the count even does not change the count of results. So it might be an idea to align n to be even and finally ignore this added number.

Comment: hmmm are you sure? I can see why results where [1] is the single element don't appear (i.e. [(2,3),(4,5),(1)]) when we do for instance [1,2,3,4,5] but I thought that my algorithm would generate all the possibilities where [2], [3], [4], [5] are the single element. Could you give me an example which is still being omitted?

Comment: So thats easy visible in your example. Take a look at first point: "add (1,2) to each list in result which gives us [ [(1,2)(3,4)(5)], [(1,2)(3,5)(4)] ]". With (1,2) we're missing here e.g. situation where (3) is alone -> (1,2)(3)(4,5). The bigger the number is (the further from 1), the more frequent it will appear as alone. E.g. (5) appears alone for every case, but (1) for none. (second case from your example is missing (2))

Comment: @yusuf ah I see you're right! BUT! :-) in that case you just need to replace the "= compute( nextStep )" in the function with the same if condition as during the initial invocation of compute()! I edited the compute method. Basically each time you want to use compute() you need to check that condition, not only the first time. My bad!

Comment: That should work, however finally I used a workaround to make the array size be even. This does not slow the computation neither change the output set. Thx for your big help

Answer (score 0):

You are processing each pair twice, to correct this replace the if condition: compare for `<` or `>` instead of `!=`.
This won't improve the performance much, but at least should work as you expect.

Comment: This in fact eliminates some of the duplicates, but still I'm facing e.g: [0 1] [2 3] vs [2 3] [0 1]